# How do I get devise current_user using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm have an app running with RoR and Devise gem. I'm trying to create an ajax and I need to pass the current_user logged in. How do I get it using jQuery?

```
_addUser: function(map, marker) {
  var data = <%= current_user %> //not work!
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : "/users",
    data: {user: data},
    beforeSend: function(x) {
      x.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
    },
    success: function(x) {
      self._resetForm(form);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything abou the Devise gem, but I'm guessing you'll find what you're looking for in the "x" variable inside the "success" function of your AJAX call. Try outputting it by putting console.log(x); inside the success function right before self._resetForm(form). See if you can find the user name in the response object.

Comment: To explain a bit more, you can't include ruby code directly in JavaScirpt. That line with <%= current_user %> will not work, because current_user is a server side Ruby variable. What you have to do is inspect the response sent back to you in your ajax call in success. Hopefully that will contain the username. Again, I'm not sure how Devise works, but I can tell you for sure that the Ruby variable above mixed in to the JavaScript will not work if the AJAX call is supposed to be getting the username. Info like that is usually passed back from the server on success.

Comment: I've figure out it. I decided to get the current_id in controller instead of in view. Thanks